# Test build on iOS 10 rather than iOS 9

Tags: ios

I want to ask that I create an app which is running on latest iOS version. But when I am checking that app on other device which has iOS version 9.3.5 (iPod touch) can be run or not. Because it is showing an error ("The iOS version didn’t install, says not compatible"). Do I need to update my iOS or this is any other issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the **Deployment Target** of your app

It should be below **iOS 10.x** version in order to make things running below **iOS 10** version devices. Make that **iOS 9.0** and it will work fine on all **iOS 9.x** devices.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But i already set the deployment target to 9.0

Comment: Did you tried on iPhone 9.x versions rather than iPod

Comment: Can you add more details, when the error comes in Xcode. Any screenshot

Comment: Actually this testing is from client side. He has iPod touch with iOS version 9.3.5. Should I tell him to update his iOS version ?

Comment: How are you installing the app?

Comment: I am simply providing build (.ipa) to him.

Comment: Are you archieving/building ipa from xcode 8.x versions? with deployment 9.x

Comment: Yes I am doing the same.